# thumbnail different from actual image in gridview

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I have created a simple GridView application in android in which the images when clicked opens up in a new window as fullscreen .

Application image :

[image]

[image]

I also put the random image generation code in the **getView** method as follows in **ImageAdapter** Class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView iv;
    shuffleArray(images);
    if(arg1!=null){
        iv=(ImageView)arg1;
    }else{
        iv=new ImageView(context);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80,80)); //resizing the picture according to the params
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);//images will be cropped towards center
        iv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8); //padding of all sides if images vary then less padding more crop to fit imageview
    }

    iv.setImageResource( images[arg0]);
    return iv;
}

static void shuffleArray(int[] images2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random rnd=new Random();
    for(int i=images2.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        int index=rnd.nextInt(i+1);
        int temp=images2[index];
        images2[index]=images2[i];
        images2[i]=temp;
    }

}
```

Every time I open app the pictures get shuffled with some problems.

Now the problem is as follows :

- Whenever I click on the image thumbnail a different image opens  in a
  new window .
- Same image thumbnail is showing in GridView Activity for two or more 
  different images.
- I am also trying to put a condition that  the app when run should
  have all Hardware buttons Disabled

**AND**

- whenever user **clicks** on a specific  NO  of images the app should
  close automatically with message .

**How should I achieve solutions of problems mentioned above** ?

my whole source code:
**Main Activity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        private boolean[] isSpecificImage;{
            isSpecificImage[0]=true;
        }





        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View iv, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageDetail.class);  // for click open that image as new activity
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);



        }

    });
```

**ImageAdapter class**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
```

private Context context;
    public static int[] images={
             R.drawable.goku,R.drawable.gohan,R.drawable.vegeta,R.drawable.broly,R.drawable.buu
     };

```
public ImageAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
     context = applicationContext;
        shuffleArray(images);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // no of items to be displayed
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView iv;

    if(arg1!=null){
        iv=(ImageView)arg1;
    }else{
        iv=new ImageView(context);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80,80)); //resizing the picture according to the params
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);//images will be cropped towards center
        iv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8); //padding of all sides if images vary then less padding more crop to fit imageview
    }

    iv.setImageResource( images[arg0]);
    return iv;
}

 void shuffleArray(int[] images2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random rnd=new Random();
    for(int i=images2.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        int index=rnd.nextInt(i+1);
        int temp=images2[index];
        images2[index]=images2[i];
        images2[i]=temp;
    }

}
```

}

**ImageDetail class**

```
public class ImageDetail extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagedetail);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    int position =(Integer) i.getExtras().get("id");
    ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivdbz);
    iv.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.images[position]);
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: `I am also trying to put a condition that the app when run should have all Hardware buttons Disabled` That has nothing to do with a grid view. You better make a separate post to ask.

Comment: What about  closing the  app when clicking on selected images in GridView ?What should I do to put this logic ?

Comment: I know how to call finish(). The question is that I want to call it   when "Selecting SPECIFIC IMAGES" . So how do I select specific images so that whenever I open the app again and click on those images the app should automatically close ?

Comment: What logic  should I put in the app source code  for "SPECIFIC IMAGES SELECT CLOSE" ?

Comment: Your own logic. So then in onItemClick you check and instead of open the activity with a full image you call finish(). `if ( isSpecificImage(position) ) finiash() else display full image;`. That you get problems while you shuffle every time is clear.

Comment: What if I have to choose 2 to 3 images to trigger finish() not just one according to your code given above ?

Comment: Instead of a a simple integer array `images[]` you better could define a class with an integer and a boolean variable. Then make an array for the instances of your class. You can set the boolean if selected. If you shuffle such an array everything stays combined.

Comment: class MyImage {int imageId; boolean selected;}; MyImage myImages [];

Comment: `iv.setImageResource( myImages[arg0].imageId);`

Comment: `if ( myImages[position].selected ) finish(); else display full image;. `

Comment: You can answer all this  separately instead writing in comment !

Comment: myImages is not getting resolved

Comment: Please show complete code in your post.

Comment: Also show how you used to fill the images array.

Comment: I will put whole source code ok

Comment: Now tell what changes should i make ?

Comment: That i already told you. But i see nothing of the things that i suggested you should do. Try to implement them first.

Comment: So you changed the correct Answer indicator to a different answer? Why?

Comment: You haven't given the answer of  3rd Problem !

Comment: Yes i know. But who did? You dont seem to apreciate my help in this way.

Comment: Ok Ok just provide code  as Answer and I will accept your answer

Comment: The code which you provided has errors

Comment: And as you asked I posted source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can work with the positions in the OnClickItemListener to put `finish()`

condition in your gridView

Answer (score 0):

```
shuffleArray(images);
```

That statement does not belong in `getView()`. You should not shuffle every time getView() is called.

Call it somewhere else.

Comment: like where ? give some example !

Comment: You already gave the answer: `Every time I open app the pictures get shuffled`. So that is not in getView().